# how can I add user who can read all tables in database and have permission to alter only one table

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a database using SQL server express 2016 for a college project and
need to learn how to add a user whom can have access to all tables, however, only be able to alter one of the tables, update, delete, etc... I'm using sql server
express 2016 management studio

Comment: Take a look at "GRANT Object Permissions" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

Add the user to the db_datareader role within the database

```
sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'db_datareader' @membername '<USERNAME>'
```

Give the user permission to alter that single table

```
grant alter on [<TABLE>] to [<USER>]
```

This will give the permissions you want. You could also create a specific database role with the correct permissions, or grant the user permissions on the schema so you should check the msdn article suggested by @randolph-west